# Consuming API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to consume an API in my react but I can't seem to load the response on my react frontend.
when I check the network on my browser, I can see the response, but it does not display on the web page.

my code is below can't seem to know what's wrong.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
 import axios from "axios";
import "./PrivateScreen.css";

const PrivateScreen = ({ history }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [privateData, setPrivateData] = useState(null);
  
   
   const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!localStorage.getItem("authToken")) {
      history.push("/login")
    }

    const fetchPrivateDate = async () => {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("authToken")}`,
        },
      };

      try {
        await axios.get(url, config)
        .then(res => {
          setPrivateData(res.data);
        });
        
      } catch (error) {
        localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
        setError("You are not authorized. Please login");
      }
    };

    fetchPrivateDate();
    
  }, [history]);

    const logoutHandler = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("authToken");
    history.push("/login");
  };

  return error ? (
    <span className="error-message">{error}</span>
  ) : (
    <>
      <div style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}>
       {privateData.name}
      </div>
      <div><p>hello from this side</p></div>
      <button onClick={logoutHandler}>Log Out</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default PrivateScreen;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: show please what you get in `res` in `then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must change  instead of

`const [privateData, setPrivateData] = useState(null);`

`const [privateData, setPrivateData] = useState([]);`

when calling the array data we want initialize an empty array

Then second when we are showing array data with help map method we want to call like this,Let me know issue is fixed

```
 {privateData.map((privateDatas) => (
    <div style={{ background: "green", color: "white" }}>
       {privateDatas.name}
    </div>
  ))}
```